# UM Modeling: Analysis Class (boundary vs. control class)

Tags: uml

I am taking a software engineering course and we use Java to implement some of the concepts. I have a question with regards to Control and Boundary Classes - I am having a hard time grasping the concept.

I have [read this previous question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla) many times and still cannot find the difference between the two:

1. **boundary classes are ones at the boundary of the system - the classes that you or other systems interact with**
2. entity classes classes are your typical business entities like "person" and "bank account"
3. **control classes implement some business logic or other**

Comment: You could have at least linked to the question that you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question where you got the summaries of boundary classes, entity classes, and control classes, there was [an answer by Ted Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla/683872#683872) with a link to [a page on the "Entity-Control-Boundary Pattern"](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openuppt/openup_basic/guidances/concepts/entity_control_boundary_pattern,_uF-QYEAhEdq_UJTvM1DM2Q.html) that might be of interest to you.

In the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla), [chimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla/684503#684503) and [KP Haldeman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cla/1060554#1060554) mention Robustness Diagrams - you can read more about them on [Agile Modeling's Introduction to Robustness Diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/robustnessDiagram.htm).

Comment: @Thomas, thanks a lot for the link, I will read through the article

Comment: If you read everything on the original question, you would have seen that link.