# Entity-Control-Boundary Pattern

Tags: uml, class-diagram, ecb-pattern

I am studying about `Entity-Control-Boundary` Pattern and trying to make class diagram for Online learning platform site. Answers from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683825/in-uml-class-diagrams-what-are-boundary-classes-control-classes-and-entity-cl) question helped me a lot. While designing `Boundary` classes I'm facing a design issue. I've not found any example of `Boundary` or `Control` classes where inheritance has been used. But In my design I'm trying to bring inheritance. 
[image]

I've converted this to the following: 
[image]

So, the partial design looks like this: 
[image]

**My questions:**

1. Is it mandatory or convention to write `<<Boundary>>` in the interface to show that it is a interface of `Boundary` class ? I've just written `<<interface>>` .
2. Should I use parameters in a `Boundary` class ? I know that the main logical work is done by the `Control` class. But user interacts with the `Boundary` class directly and then `Boundary` class passes information to `Control` class.
3. If I chose selectTutorial operation of `TutorialListUI` user's Boundary class will be changed to `IndividualTutorialUI` . Should I just draw a line between these two `Boundary` classes to show the transition ?
4. Apart from these, please mention any improvements that can be made.

Answer (score 2):

1. Writing just `<<interface>>` is correct.
2. The boundary class *usually* just holds attributes which usually correspond to screen fields and operations corresponding buttons.
3. No. This is behavior and does not fit in a (static) class diagram.
4. see below

   - Your boundaries rather look like being controllers.
   - You write *"But In my design I'm trying to bring inheritance."* but you rather (correctly) use a realization in your diagram
   - There should be tons of examples out there. Also look for MVC which is almost the same with other words (I said almost!).

Comment: Thanks. how can I redesign my diagrams so that it doesn't look like `Controller` s rather look like `Boundary` ??

Comment: Show us your (partial) design with ECB and not just what you call the boundary and we'll have a look.

Comment: Sorry for late. I've just edited my question to add the partial design. Please check that.

Comment: Hm. That looks just strange. Why would you have the boundaries an interface which does not seem to be used? Boundaries should be focused on data interchange with the user. None of your boundaries appear to be designed that way.  An this `startInterface(), what could that be at all?